# Como hacer una sección de código en HTML y CSS, estilizado y descrito como una sección de codigo

Tags: javascript, html, python, css

Quiero saber como se puede estilizar el código en HTML y con CSS para estilizar el texto y expresar secciones de código, como lo hacen las paginas para expresar una sección de código.[image: Ejemplo de como quiero estilizado el texto y una seccion de codigo]

Comment: ¿Algo como Jupyter Notebooks? https://jupyter.org/

Comment: Probablemente [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/usage/) puede servirte.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<fieldset>
  <p>Tal vez te refires a esto</p>
</fieldset>
```